# Comparar valores de variáveis e escolher as maiores para calcular

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, matemática

Estou desenvolvendo uma calculadora de aposentadoria. Diponível no link http://www.utilizaweb.com.br/aposentadoria (código tambem disponível abaixo). O programa trabalha com a inserção de várias empresas. Preciso que quando o usuário dê a entrada de por exemplo:
(para usuário masculino)

Se o usuario  trabalhou na primeira empresa, pela regra dos 25 anos, o tempo de 6 anos;
Se o usuario  trabalhou na segunda empresa, pela regra dos 25 anos, o tempo de 2 anos;
Se o usuario  trabalhou na terceira empresa, pela regra dos 15 anos, o tempo de 4 anos;
Se o usuario  trabalhou na quarta empresa, pela regra dos 20 anos, o tempo de 3 anos;

O programa deve pegar as regras maiores, no caso as duas de 25 anos, somar o tempo trabalhado nas duas, multiplicar por 1.4 e subtrair por 35.

Eu queria agora é saber como eu faço para comparar em todos os campos, quais são as regras, pegar as maiores que sejam iguais, somar a quantidade de tempo trabalhado e continuar a conta. Muito Obrigado :)

html

```
<div class="container">
<h3><span>Saiba quando você irá se aposentar!</span><br />Preencha suas informações abaixo!</h3>
<form class="form-calculadora" name="aposentadoria">

    <fieldset class="sexo">
        <legend>Sexo</legend>
        <select id="sexo" name="sexo" class="text-area">
            <option value="M"><i class="fa fa-male"></i>Masculino</option>
            <option value="F"><i class="fa fa-female"></i>Feminino</option>
        </select>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset class="trabalho">
        <div class="row" id="p_scents">
                            <div class="empresa-area">
                <p class="title">Empresa</p>
                <input type="text" name="empresa" class="text-area" placeholder="Empresa: ">
            </div>

            <div class="regra-area">
                <p class="title">Regra</p>
                <select name="regra" class="text-area">
                    <option value="25">25 anos</option>
                    <option value="20">20 anos</option>
                    <option value="15">15 anos</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="admissao-area">
                <p class="title">Admissão</p>
                <input type="date" name="dataAdmissao" class="text-area" placeholder="Admissão: ">
            </div>

            <div class="demissao-area">
                <p class="title">Demissão</p>
                <input type="date" name="dataDemissao" class="text-area" placeholder="Demissão: ">
            </div>

            <div class="anos-area">
                <p id="anosTrabalhados">0 Anos</p>
            </div>
        </div>


    </fieldset>

    <p class="add-empresa"><a href="#" id="addScnt"><i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i> Adicionar Empresa</a></p>

    <input type="button" value="Calcular" onclick="calcula();" >

</form>

<p id="result"><img src="./img/aviso.png"></p>
```

Javascript

```
function calcula(){
var sexo = document.aposentadoria.sexo.value;
var nRegra = document.aposentadoria.regra.value;
var empresa = document.aposentadoria.empresa.value;
var dataAdmissao = new Date(document.aposentadoria.dataAdmissao.value);
var dataDemissao = new Date(document.aposentadoria.dataDemissao.value);

if (dataDemissao > dataAdmissao) {;
    var anosTrab = dataDemissao.getFullYear() - dataAdmissao.getFullYear();
    var dateTrab = dataDemissao.getDate() - dataAdmissao.getDate();
    var mesTrab = dataDemissao.getMonth() - dataAdmissao.getMonth();
} else {
    alert("A data de admissão deve ser anterior à data de demissão.");
}

if ((sexo == "M") && (nRegra == "25")) {
    anosNovo = anosTrab * 1.40;
} else if ((sexo == "M") && (nRegra == "20")) {
    anosNovo = anosTrab * 1.75;
} else if ((sexo == "M") && (nRegra == "15")) {
    anosNovo = anosTrab * 2.33;
} else if ((sexo == "F") && (nRegra == "25")) {
    anosNovo = anosTrab * 1.20;
} else if ((sexo == "F") && (nRegra == "20")) {
    anosNovo = anosTrab * 1.50;
} else if ((sexo == "F") && (nRegra == "15")) {
    anosNovo = anosTrab * 2;
}


if (sexo == "M") {
    anosFalta = anosNovo - 35;
} else if (sexo == "F") {
    anosFalta = anosNovo - 30;
}

if (anosFalta < 0) {
    anosFim = anosFalta * -1;
}

var anosAjus = "Você trabalhou " +anosTrab+ " anos " +mesTrab+ " meses e " +dateTrab+ " dias";
var calculoNovaR = "Faltam " +anosFim+ " anos para se aposentar";

document.getElementById("anosTrabalhados").innerHTML = anosTrab+ " anos";
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "<img src='./img/aviso.png'>" +anosAjus+ "<br />" +calculoNovaR;}
```

JQuery para ADD mais campos

```
$(function() {
var scntDiv = $('#p_scents');
var i = $('#p_scents p').size() + 1;

$('#addScnt').live('click', function() {
    $('<div class="row"><div class="empresa-area"><input type="text" name="empresa' + i +'" class="text-area" placeholder="Empresa: "></div><div class="regra-area"><select name="regra' + i +'" class="text-area"><option value="25">25 anos</option><option value="20">20 anos</option><option value="15">15 anos</option></select></div><div class="admissao-area"><input type="date" name="dataAdmissao' + i +'" class="text-area" placeholder="Admissão: "></div><div class="demissao-area"><input type="date" name="dataDemissao' + i +'" class="text-area" placeholder="Demissão: "></div><div class="anos-area"><p id="anosTrabalhados">0 Anos</p></div></div>').appendTo(scntDiv);
                i++;
                return false;
});

$('#remScnt').live('click', function() { 
    if( i > 2 ) {
        $(this).parents('p').remove();
        i--;
    }
    return false;
});
```

});

Comment: Olá. É possivel colocar o exemplo no jsfiddle. Fica mais facil ajudar.

Comment: No entretanto a solução deve passar por:
No "calcular" passar por todos os registos neste caso $('.row').each(); dentro desse each deve fazer o calculo e gravar os valores para então no fim saber quais que pretende.